# Как изменять никнейм пользователя, при получении роли discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

Пишу бота на discord.py, и мне нужно для рп сервера, что бы когда пользователь получал определенную роль его ник изменялся. И + нужно сделать проверку, что бы если пользователь этот ник убрал, то он снова изменился. Как это сделать?

Comment: Используйте событие [`on_member_update()`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.on_member_update). Смотрите изменилась ли роль на нужную (или изменился ник) и в соответствии с этим меняйте ник

Answer (score 0):

что бы изменить никнейм упомянутому пользователю, вы должны указать после ctx это:
discord.Member и nickname. и после этого использовать `await member.edit(nick = nickname)`. А что бы участники не могли сменить никнейм, просто запретите им это.

Comment: А как понять когда роль была выдана, чтобы в нужное время изменить ник?

Comment: зачем это делать? просто выдай роль которая запретит участнику изменять никнейм и все

Comment: В вопросе было сказано: `когда пользователь получал определенную роль`, я говорю про то чтобы ник изменялся только тогда когда выдавалась нужная роль, внимательней перечитайте вопрос и попробуйте корректней написать ответ. Ну если говорить про запрет изменения никнейма, то это вы правильно отметили.